# Resolving potential inconsistency between two data stream in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

We want to redesign our legacy monolith application to EDA. We are uncertain about the best approach to design the following system in order to prevent faults.

With regard to the attached illustrated design, we want to handle the following problem.

The issue arises from the potential inconsistency between the "ProductionLine Processor" and the "Task Processor." When there is an inconsistency in their states, it can lead to faulty data being generated. For instance, a task may be generated for a production line that has already been deleted by the Production Line Processor. Because, the Task Processor is not yet been informed of this change.

"The red lines in the diagram represent the problematic late data".

We are eager to hear your ideas, even if they involve fundamental changes to the architecture, as we are still in the early stages of design.

[image]